# How to get the SPRING Boot HOST and PORT address during run time?

Tags: spring-boot, port, host

How could I get the host and port where my application is deployed during run-time so that I can use it in my java method?

Comment: How do you define the port of spring boot application ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get local server host and port in Spring Boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29929896/how-to-get-local-server-host-and-port-in-spring-boot)

Comment: This solved my issue, alltogether:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75722327/how-to-get-host-url-in-spring-boot-controller

Answer (score 59):

You can get this information via [`Environment`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/Environment.html) for the [`port`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html) and the `host` you can obtain by using `InternetAddress`.

```
@Autowired
Environment environment;

// Port via annotation
@Value("${server.port}")
int aPort;

......
public void somePlaceInTheCode() {
    // Port
    environment.getProperty("server.port");
    
    // Local address
    InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();
    InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName();
    
    // Remote address
    InetAddress.getLoopbackAddress().getHostAddress();
    InetAddress.getLoopbackAddress().getHostName();
}
```

Comment: Getting the port this way will only work, if a) the port is actually configured explicitly, and b) it is not set to 0 (meaning the servlet container will choose a random port on startup). To get the actual port, you need to implement `ApplicationListener<EmbeddedServletContainerInitializedEvent>` and get the port from the provided event.

Comment: Using `local.server.port` instead of `server.port` would be a better choice in the case of random port is used(`server.port=0`).

Comment: The loopback address(127.0.0.1) is a remote address?

Comment: what is the difference between "Local address" and "Remote address" address?

Answer (score 11):

If you use random port like `server.port=${random.int[10000,20000]}` method. and in Java code read the port in `Environment` use `@Value` or `getProperty("server.port")`.  **You will get a Unpredictable Port Because it is Random.**

ApplicationListener, you can override onApplicationEvent to get the port number once it's set.

In Spring boot version Implements Spring interface `ApplicationListener<EmbeddedServletContainerInitializedEvent>`(Spring boot version 1) or `ApplicationListener<WebServerInitializedEvent>`(Spring boot version 2) override onApplicationEvent to get the Fact Port .

Spring boot 1

```
@Override
public void onApplicationEvent(EmbeddedServletContainerInitializedEvent event) {
    int port = event.getEmbeddedServletContainer().getPort();
}
```

Spring boot 2

```
@Override
public void onApplicationEvent(WebServerInitializedEvent event) {
    Integer port = event.getWebServer().getPort();
    this.port = port;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is an util component:

**EnvUtil.java**
*(Put it in proper package, to become a component.)*

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

/**
 * Environment util.
 */
@Component
public class EnvUtil {
    @Autowired
    Environment environment;

    private String port;
    private String hostname;

    /**
     * Get port.
     *
     * @return
     */
    public String getPort() {
        if (port == null) port = environment.getProperty("local.server.port");
        return port;
    }

    /**
     * Get port, as Integer.
     *
     * @return
     */
    public Integer getPortAsInt() {
        return Integer.valueOf(getPort());
    }

    /**
     * Get hostname.
     *
     * @return
     */
    public String getHostname() throws UnknownHostException {
        // TODO ... would this cache cause issue, when network env change ???
        if (hostname == null) hostname = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();
        return hostname;
    }

    public String getServerUrlPrefi() throws UnknownHostException {
        return "http://" + getHostname() + ":" + getPort();
    }
}
```

**Example - use the util:**

Then could inject the util, and call its method.
Here is an example in a controller:

```
// inject it,
@Autowired
private EnvUtil envUtil;

/**
 * env
 *
 * @return
 */
@GetMapping(path = "/env")
@ResponseBody
public Object env() throws UnknownHostException {
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("port", envUtil.getPort());
    map.put("host", envUtil.getHostname());
    return map;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For the Host:
As mentionned by Anton

```
// Local address
InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();
InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName();

// Remote address
InetAddress.getLoopbackAddress().getHostAddress();
InetAddress.getLoopbackAddress().getHostName();
```

Port:
As mentioned by Nicolai, you can retrieve this information by the environment property only if it is configured explicitly and not set to 0.

Spring documentation on the subject:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-embedded-servlet-containers.html#howto-discover-the-http-port-at-runtime

For the actual way to do this, it was answered here:
[Spring Boot - How to get the running port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30312058/spring-boot-how-to-get-the-running-port)

And here's a github example on how to implement it:
https://github.com/hosuaby/example-restful-project/blob/master/src/main/java/io/hosuaby/restful/PortHolder.java

Answer (score 2):

Just a complete example for answers above

```
package bj;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.context.event.ApplicationReadyEvent;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;

import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

@SuppressWarnings("SpringJavaAutowiredFieldsWarningInspection")
@SpringBootApplication
class App implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationReadyEvent> {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationReadyEvent event) {
        try {
            String ip = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();
            int port = applicationContext.getBean(Environment.class).getProperty("server.port", Integer.class, 8080);
            System.out.printf("%s:%d", ip, port);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

The port has been bind in runtime could been injected as:

```
@Value('${local.server.port}')
private int port;
```