# How to determine on which server running spring job - Hostname

Tags: java, spring, scheduled-tasks

I have simple spring job with schedule annotation. Is there some way how to determine on which server it runs? We use Tomcat as web server.

Comment: e.g. by using Spring evironment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38916213/how-to-get-the-spring-boot-host-and-port-address-during-run-time

Comment: Unfortunatelly it dont return hostname but ip address, which I dont need.

Comment: take the ip, create an InetAddress and use InetAddress.getHostName()