# How to get host url in spring boot controller?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I want to generate dynamic URL for my home page, how to get host URL in spring boot app.

get Host url
exp: https://localhost:8080/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ServletUriComponentsBuilder`.

```java
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.ServletUriComponentsBuilder;
// ...
String homeURL = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentContextPath().toUriString();
```

Comment: Does that contain the hostname? If so, which hostname is it? The one used in the latest/current request?

Comment: @f1sh Yes, it contains the hostname and it's obtained from the current request. Docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/support/ServletUriComponentsBuilder.html#fromContextPath(jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)

Comment: How does this not have a single vote at all. This was the solution for me 100%. 
Port, http/https, hostname all were solved. It also contains the app context. Thanks

Comment: Doesn't work if you're not handling a request.